# Node.js send mysql data to HTML table parse problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I need help!

I am currently trying to create a node file that shows data from mysql on a HTML page with a search bar. My problem is that currently If I run the codes, enter something to the search bar and hit the button it is sometimes working, sometimes it does not. Sometimes it works 5 times in a row, after a reload it maybe doesn't even show anything at all.

I have the following codes:

My node.js server.js file:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var url = require('url');
var qs = require('querystring');

var valami;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "uzeno"
});

var data = [];

function connectToDb(){
  connection.connect(function(err){
    if (err){
      console.log('error: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
    return console.log('Connected established!');
  });
}

var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';

        request.on('data', function(data) {
            body += data;
            valami = body;
            console.log("valami = " + valami);
            
        });

        request.on('end', function() {
            var post = qs.parse(body);
        });
        }   
      var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
      fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, file) {  
        if(err) {   
            return;  
            }  
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });  
            response.end(file, "utf-8");  
        });
  if(request.method == "POST") {
  } else if (request.method == "GET") {
if (request.url == '/get-servers/'){
  connection.query('call kereses(?)', [valami], function(err,rows)    {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return
    }    
    for (i=0 ; i < rows.length ; i++){
        var row = rows[i];
        for(q=0 ; q < row.length; q++){
            var ro = row[q];    
            data[q] ='<p>'+  ro.ID + '<td>' + ro.Sender + '<td>' + ro.Receiver +'<td>' + ro.Targy +'<td>' + ro.Tartalom+ '<br>';
                
    }   
    var teszt = JSON.stringify(data);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(teszt);
    }       
  });
    }
  }  
}).listen(8002);
```

My html index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Teszt</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style> 
table#servers {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0em 2em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
  }
    
tr {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

tr{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>
<input type="text" id="valamiInput" />
<button id="valami">Keresés</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
  <table id="servers">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="75">ID</th>
        <th width="75">Sender</th>
        <th width="75">Receiver</th>
        <th width="150">Tárgy</th>
        <th width="150">Tartalom</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="log"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#valami").click(function(){
            var x;
            var serverData = [];
            x = $("#valamiInput").val();
            $("#demo").text("Keresés a következőre: "+x);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
            xhr.send(x);
            $.get('/get-servers/', function(data) {
            var serverData = JSON.parse(data);
            var rows = serverData.length ;
          
                  for (i=0 ; i < rows ; i++){
                    $('#servers tbody').append('<tr><td>'+serverData[i]);
                  }
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error (you can see on the right, that it works sometimes):
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd4HC.png)
IF I debug.log data after the :

```
var jqxhr = $.get('/get-servers/', function(data) {
```

then if it successful, it shows the things that would be parsed into the tables. But if the parsing would fail, then it would show the HTML page full code in the console. (like everything, from the starting  tag until the  tag

Thanks for the suggestions in advance! (Also, sorry for my bad english)

Comment: the `JSON` that you are parsing and that causes the error would be helpful in diagnosing your issue.  You should be able to `console.log(data)` before you call `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: When there is an error, and it doesn't run the console.log(data) returns what is inside the html file. The hole page code is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON parse is failing, you could start by logging the server response before you try to parse it to see if the response format is causing any issues or is being returned null.

On Index.html ln 58 add:

```
 console.log(data);
```

Comment: The log returns what is inside the index.html file.
I just realized it is maybe because when I load the index.html I also use response.end and maybe that's why it shows what is inside that html file.

Comment: Also, apparently you are sending two requests, that may be causing asynchronous issues.. The first one being a POST request using the XMLHttpRequest library, and after that you are using the JQuery get request.. Try using one POST request that sends out the input value and also returns the desired data in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply returning the result set, as you do not seem to be doing any additional filtering or logic

```js
//.....snip.....//
connection.query('call kereses(?)', [valami], function(err, rows) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return
  }
  data = rows;
  var teszt = JSON.stringify(data);
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  response.end(teszt);
});
//.....snip.....//
```

and then allowing the receiver to process the `json` for display purposes

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#valami").click(function() {
    var x;
    //var serverData = [];
    x = $("#valamiInput").val();
    $("#demo").text("Keresés a következőre: " + x);

    $.get('/get-servers/', function(data) {
      var serverData = JSON.parse(data);
      var body = $('#servers tbody');
      body.empty(); //clean it out
      $.each(serverData, function(idx, elem) {
        body.append(
          $(`<tr><td>${elem.ID}</td><td>${elem.Sender}</td><td>${elem.Receiver}</td><td>${elem.Targy}</td><td>${elem.Tartalom}</td></tr>`));
      });
    });
  });
});
```